# How to create FuncAnimation (matplotlib) animation from plt.imshow and animate text in double for loop?

Tags: python, plot, animated-gif, imshow, matplotlib-animation

**LONG POST:** I know many posts are available on StackOverflow on a similar topic, but none worked for me so far. The animation is either not fast enough, or the text is animated (not how I want), but the plot isn't. Any help is appreciated.

Hello,

I am implementing self-organizing maps and **would like to create a gif file of the changing weights and plot text i.e. title.**

```
X, Y  = np.meshgrid(np.arange(w.shape[0]), np.arange(w.shape[1]))
pos = np.array((X,Y))
som = SelfOrganizingMap(grid_pos=pos)

data = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (100, 3))
num_dims = data.shape[-1]
n_neuron = 5*np.sqrt(data.shape[0])
dim = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(n_neuron)))
w = np.random.uniform(np.min(data), np.max(data), (dim, dim, num_dims))
for step in range(max_steps):
    for t in range(len(data)):
        euclidean_distance = som.e_distance(weights = w, x = data[t])
        distance_node, bmu = som.winning_neuron(euclidean_distance)
        influence_radius = som.decay(distance_node)
        w += learning_rate * influence_radius[:, :, None] * (data[t] - w) #create gif of this
```

The parameters are as follows:

- w.shape=(8,8,3)
- max_steps = 200
- som = SelfOrganizingMaps() i.e. an instance of the class
- data.shape =(100,3) and len(data) = 100
- learning_rate = 0.01

So far I have tried the following:

---

**Try #1**

```
@gif.frame
def animate(weight):
    plt.imshow(weight)
    plt.axis('off')
```

and then in the main code:

```
frames = []
gif.options.matplotlib["dpi"] = 300
for step in range(max_steps):
     for t in range(len(data)):
          euclidean_distance = som.e_distance(weights = w, x = data[t])
          distance_node, bmu = som.winning_neuron(euclidean_distance)
          influence_radius = som.decay(distance_node)
          w += learning_rate * influence_radius[:, :, None] * (data[t] - w)
          frames.append(animate(weight = w))

gif.save(frames, "color_som.gif", duration=15)
```

The execution is killed because of the memory issue.

---

**Try #2:**

```
def animate(weight):
   text = axes.text(0.5,1.05, 'Iteration: {}'.format(step), horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='bottom',transform=axes.transAxes)
   im = axes.imshow(weight)
   axes.axis('off')
   frames.append([im, text])
   return frames
```

and then in the main code:

```
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
for step in range(max_steps):
     for t in range(len(data)):
          euclidean_distance = som.e_distance(weights = w, x = data[t])
          distance_node, bmu = som.winning_neuron(euclidean_distance)
          influence_radius = som.decay(distance_node)
          w += learning_rate * influence_radius[:, :, None] * (data[t] - w)
          images = animate(weight = w)

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, images, interval=1, blit=False, repeat_delay=50)
ani.save("./color_som.gif", writer='pillow', fps=30)
```

This works fine if max_steps is set to lower values but is extremely slow if it is set to higher values. The execution time for max_steps = 50 is 250.62131214141846

---

**Try #3:**

```
# initialize elements to be animated

plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})
fig, axes = plt.subplots()

w_plot = axes.imshow(w)
axes.axis('off')

def update_data(t, lr, x, w, w_plot):

    euclidean_distance = som.e_distance(weights=w, x=x[t])
    distance_node, bmu = som.winning_neuron(euclidean_distance)
    influence_radius = som.decay(distance_node)
    w += lr * influence_radius[:, :, None] * (x[t] - w)
    w_plot.set_data(w)
    step_txt.set_text("step: {}".format(t))

step_txt = fig.text(0.5, 0.95, "step: 0", ha="center", weight="bold")

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, func = partial(update_data, lr = 0.1, x=data, w=w, w_plot= w_plot), frames= len(data), interval=300, repeat_delay=500)
anim.save("test.gif")
```

This works and is pretty fast (execution time=3.0469424724578857), but this is not what I want because:

1. I want to separate the calculation from the animation. I want to have a for loop outside the update_data.
2. The above code runs only for len(data) times, i.e. 100, instead of max_steps times, i.e. 200. I cannot set frames = max_steps in FuncAnimation; otherwise, it will give an error because of x[t]. So, it just executes the inner for loop i.e.

> for t in range(len(data)):

I want animation with double for loop executed

---

**Try #4**

I also tried this "[Creating matplotlib animation from plt.imshow in triple for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379704/creating-matplotlib-animation-from-plt-imshow-in-triple-for-loop)",

```
# initialize elements to be animated

plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
w_plot = axes.imshow(w)
step_txt = fig.text(0.5, 0.95, "step: 0", ha="center", weight="bold")

def update_data(t):
    w_plot.set_data(wei[t])
    step_txt.set_text("step: {}".format(t))

weight = []
for step in range(max_steps):
    for t in range(len(data)):
        euclidean_distance = som.e_distance(weights = w, x = data[t])
        distance_node, bmu = som.winning_neuron(euclidean_distance)
        influence_radius = som.decay(distance_node)
        w += learning_rate * influence_radius[:, :, None] * (data[t] - w)
        weight.append(w)

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, func = update_data, frames= len(data), interval=50, repeat_delay=500) #, max_steps= max_steps #len(data)
anim.save("test.gif")#, writer="pillow")
```

This separates the calculation from the animation and executes double "for" loop.

Also, **when I save the animation as gif, the animation is on the text but not the plot itself. It takes only the final plot. Also, I want step text to change from 0,1,....499 (for max_steps = 500)** instead of step = 0,1...99 (i.e. len(data))

I also tried [celluloid package in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73433714/how-to-animate-plt-imshow-with-text), it did not work for me.

***How to get a gif image of the weights with both the for loop executed and text change to step values (i.e. outer loop value) instead of t value (i.e. inner for loop)?***

Comment: I'd try saving each individual plot/subplot as a png file, then reading/iterating through the saved png files to make a gif. I'm not a huge fan of `FuncAnimation`.

Comment: @OriYardenPhD I did think about doing that, but unfortunately it is not memory efficient. If my max_steps is 200, then for every max step, the inner loop runs 100 times (len(data)), that's 20000 images. For some other input data, it will be many more or fewer images depending on the len(data).

Comment: @OriYardenPhD Also, reading 20000 images from the folder and creating a gif image from them will also be time-consuming. Even, I am not a huge fan of FuncAnimation, but it is fast and memory efficient too. I am not adamant about using FuncAnimation. I don't mind any other better solution if it is fast and memory efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution is:

```
# Initialize elements to be animated

fig, axes = plt.subplots()
w_plot = axes.imshow(w)
step_txt = fig.text(0.5, 0.95, "step: 0", ha="center", weight="bold")

def update_data(t):
    w_plot.set_data(wei[t])
    if t%len(data)==0:
        step_txt.set_text("step: {}".format(np.divmod(t, len(data))[0]))

weight = []
for step in range(max_steps):
    for t in range(len(data)):
        euclidean_distance = som.e_distance(weights = w, x = data[t])
        distance_node, bmu = som.winning_neuron(euclidean_distance)
        influence_radius = som.decay(distance_node)
        w += learning_rate * influence_radius[:, :, None] * (data[t] - w)
        weight.append(w.tolist()

weight = np.array(weight)
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, func = update_data, frames= max_steps*len(data), interval=50, repeat_delay=500) #, max_steps= max_steps #len(data)
anim.save("test.gif")
```

The gif file introduces some static in the animation. For that, you can either specify fps or dpi or both, but it will increase the execution time, and if max_steps is high, then it will take a lot of time. Alternatively, one can save the animation as .mp4 file. It doesn't introduce any static in the animation.

```
anim.save("test.mp4")
```